# Tag merge suggestion

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I think that [notes](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notes) and [annotations](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/annotations) are basically referring to the same thing, and thus they could be merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree. I have merged the annotations and notes tags (I think annotations is more correct, so have made that the tag that will stick around).